# Cauchy theorem and singularity

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

[image]
For part a, since 0 is the singularity of the function, and it is inside the unit circle, why is the integration equal to $2\pi i$?

For part b, if we've proved part a, then we can substitute z with $cos\theta$ in it, but I get $2\pi$ instead of $\pi$. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hinzt: a) Follows from the Residue theorem.

b) Observe
\begin{align}
\int_C \frac{e^{az}}{z}\ dz =&\ \int^{\pi}_{-\pi} e^{a(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)}e^{-i\theta}(ie^{i\theta})\ d\theta\\
=&\ \int^{\pi}_{-\pi} e^{a\cos\theta}[\cos a\sin  \theta+ i\sin a\sin \theta]i\ d\theta= 2\pi i
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
2\int^\pi_0e^{a\cos\theta} \cos a\sin \theta\ d\theta =\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}e^{a\cos\theta} \cos a\sin \theta\ d\theta = 2\pi.
\end{align}

Comment: Could you please take a look at this problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1961868/cauchy-theorem-practice

Comment: And for part a, what if z is not in the unit circle, then shouldn't the integration be 0?

Comment: If the curve circle the origin, then the integral will not be zero.